# How to handle webview back press in fragment

Tags: android, webview, fragment, android-webview, back

I want to back press feature in web-view for go to previous page in web-view (in fragment)...

[Here is the fragment code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGlJ2.png)

I tried adding following code which is not working:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
        if(Wv.canGoBack()){
            Wv.goBack();
            return true;
        }
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: you can use my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45430033/3999826

Answer (score 1):

This Work for me

```
public class MyWebView extends Fragment {
    private WebView mWebView;
    private View rootView;
    private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.what) {
                case 1:{
                    webViewGoBack();
                }break;
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.testwebview, null);
        mWebView = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);


        mWebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        mWebView.loadUrl("myurl...");
        mWebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener(){

            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
                        && event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                        && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

        });
            return rootView;
    }

    private void webViewGoBack(){
        mWebView.goBack();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the instance of your `Fragment` in you activity, and override the `onBackPressed` method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if(fragment.webView.canGoBack()){
        fragment.webView.goBack();
    } else{
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: sir what is fragment

Comment: instance of your `Fragment`.

Comment: can you edit your question and post your source code?

Comment: when i put code here stackoverflow tall me over code

Comment: this is my sorce code link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8YTgurIRbm5ajZaY3NZR2FxMjA

Comment: You should override `onBackPressed` in the activity, not in the fragment.

Comment: back press for webview

Comment: Sir one more question : 
I have a webview in my app in this app I add a YouTube link so when I play video in my webview video was playing but when I go to another activity video was still playing, I want that video was stop when I go to another activity.
How to do that sir....