# How to use onBackPress in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

In my application I use `ViewPager` for show two fragments in an activity.
In one of the fragments I use `NavigationDrawer`. I want when click on **`onBackPress`** close this `NavigationDrawer`.

I wrote below code for **open this Drawer :**

```
reviewSerialFrag_DrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.END);
```

I want that when I click on onBackPress it will close this drawer with below code:

```
reviewSerialFrag_DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
```

**questioner, put in what the current problem is, please**

Comment: Is you app contains multiple drawers?

Comment: @JRamesh, in my application I use Drawer in one of fragments

Answer (score 1):

`onBackpress()` only called in fragment if you need back press event in fragment you have to implement **interface** to get `onBackPress()` callback.

**In Activity:**

```
public MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private BackPressListener backPressListener;

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (backPressListener != null) {
            backPressListener.onActivityBackPress();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void setBackPressListener(BackPressListener backPressListener) {
        this.backPressListener = backPressListener;
    }

    public interface BackPressListener{
        void onActivityBackPress();
    }

}
```

**In Fragment:**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements BackPressListener{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).setBackPressListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityBackPress() {
        // handle your back press here.

       reviewSerialFrag_DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);

       getActivity().onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        ((MyActivity)getActivity()).setBackPressListener(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you send to me code? I am amateur, please my friend. I really need your help. please

Comment: can you help me?

Comment: check my updated answer. you can now handle back press in fragment

Comment: Thanks my bro, where can I use this code : `reviewSerialFrag_DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);` ?

Comment: you have to call inside the `onActivityBackPress()` method. See my updated answer.

Comment: when run app show me this error : `java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB`

Comment: You are doing somthing in infinite recursion. Please check your code

Answer (score 1):

My solution:
Create BaseFragment.java:

```
public class BaseFragment extends Fragment
    {
        public boolean onBackPressed()
        {
             return false;
        }
    }
```

then extend your fragment by this BaseFragment, and **in activity**:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    if (!yourFragment.onBackPressed())
        super.onBackPressed();
}
```

In **yourFragment**:

```
public class YourFragment extends BaseFragmnet
{

    ...
    .
    .

    @Override
    public boolean onBackPressed()
    {
        // do something...

        return true; // you should return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [AndroidX release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/androidx-rn#2018-nov), `androidx.activity 1.0.0-alpha01` is released and introduces `ComponentActivity`, a new base class of the existing `FragmentActivity` and `AppCompatActivity`. And this release brings us a new feature:

**You can now register an `OnBackPressedCallback` via `addOnBackPressedCallback` to receive `onBackPressed()` callbacks without needing to override the method in your activity.**

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is create your interface, and implement in Fragment.

Solution [here : implement onBackpress in Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425415/6831069)

```
public interface IOnBackPressed {
    /**
     * Si vous retouné true le back press ne sera pas pris en compte, sinon l'activité agira naturellement
     * @return true si votre traitement est prioritaire sinon false
     */
    boolean onBackPressed();
}
```

see link for more details ... [easy sample](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425415/6831069)

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the flag that drawer was opened. And when you override the onBackPressed(), check this flag and if it's true, call

```
reviewSerialFrag_DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.END);
```

otherwise, call super.onBackPressed() or any other logic you need.