# How to handle the backpressed while using tabactivity and fragment

Tags: android, fragment

I am using an `activtity` in which it is placed by `fragment A`. `fragment A` contains 3 tabs `tab A`, `tab B` and `tab C` on app launches the `tab B` is shown. These 3 tabs have a list when any of the list is clicked the `fragment A` is replaced by `fragment B`, when backpressed from `fragment B` it should show the tab from which it have been clicked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can you post what you've tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this. Its awesome example to implement `onBackPressed()` functionality  on `Fragment` by using `Abstract Class` and `Backable Fragment`.

**1) Create an Abstract Class -**

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;

public abstract class BackableFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnKeyListener {

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        view.requestFocus();
        view.setOnKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                onBackButtonPressed();
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public abstract void onBackButtonPressed();
}
```

**2) Implement the `Abstract Class` to your `Fragment`  -**

```
public class FragmentChannels extends BackableFragment {

    ...

    @Override
    public void onBackButtonPressed() {
        if (doTheThingRequiringBackButtonOverride) {
            // do the thing
        } else {
            //go to your preferable fragment or activity when you press back on any fragment  
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Thats it. 
[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this in on click 

view = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.activity_page1);
                ViewPager viewPager= (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                int tab = viewPager.getCurrentItem();
                tab--;
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab);
```