# How to continue to the next fragment by the click of a button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I was thinking of doing something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24881908/4742075) but the opposite. Suppose I have a continue button in the parent activity's action bar. I have several fragments that should be displayed in order. How do I go to the next fragment by just clicking the continue button?

Comment: add new fragment to backstack.

Comment: @kimkevin, Thanks, but can you elaborate? I was thinking of creating a method that can be called inside the onClickListener of the continue button from the parent activity. Is that where I'm supposed to add the new fragment to the backstack?

Comment: setOnClickListener to your view in parent Activity then you can add any fragment you want. show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `OnClick` of the Continue Button Just Replace or Add New Fragment to the `Container`.

In `Onclick`  of **Continue** Button Do nested if else or switch:

```
Fragment f = getActivity().getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
if (f instanceof FirstFFragmentClass) {
// do something with f
    FragmentTransaction ft = getActivity().getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    SecondFragmentClass secondFragment = new SecondFragmentClass();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, secondFragment);

} else if (f instanceof SecondFragmentClass){

}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering if `getActivity()` is still necessary while I'm in the actual activity?

Comment: If you are in actual activity then you can avoid `getActivity()`

Answer (score 0):

Call from your main activity a method that does:

```
Fragment myNewFragment = MyFragmentClass.newInstance();
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myNewFragment, "newTag");
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```

Where R.id.fragment_container is a maybe a FrameLayout or other layout in your XML, myNewFragment is a Fragment returned by creating a new Fragment object or perhaps a custom method like newInstance() that you can pass an argument to use the same Fragment class but layout different views/text.