# Suppress moving away from a fragment until confirmed

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an android app that has a timer that when expires plays a sound.

I have the following code to capture when a user tries to navigate away from the fragment;

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (gameOn == 1) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to cancel the match?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setTitle("Cancel match?")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //do things
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
    }
}
```

The problem I have is I want to add in an additional option (YES / NO, which I know how to do) that suppresses the user from navigating away without making the choice too (the UI could mean a user accidentally navigates away from the fragment, this is a fail safe, are you really sure question).

onPause does trigger the alert dialog to pop-up but behind it the new fragment has already loaded and as far as I'm aware onPause is the first of the events triggered when a user moves away from a fragment.

All help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you simply use a [DialogFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) with `setCancelable(false)`?

Answer (score 1):

When `onPause()` is called it's already too late to undo the `transaction`. It's committed. I cannot see how many click options you have in your `fragment` to navigate away but I can suggest to add in `onClickListeners` this `alert dialogue` you create wherever you need your additional "check". You could make it a separate method `showDialogue` for example and put you code there and then call it `onclick`. So you won't have repeated code. The in positive button click segment you just put your `fragmenttransaction` code.

Maybe you'll need to override the `backpress` too. Refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments)