# When i press backpress on fragment it doesn't redirect to parent activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

```
 if (User.getUser(getContext()).getToken()!=null){
    Intent intent =new Intent(getContext(),UserProfileActivity.class);
   startActivity(intent);}
```

Then I open a fragment from that activity

```
   mCvAboutUS.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("aboutUs", "aboutUs");
        mFragment = new TextDisplayFragment();
        mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        llMainProfile.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        replaceFragment(mFragment);
```

here the method replaceFragment

```
 public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.frameLayout, fragment)
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .commit();
}
```

Comment: Provide your code . See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks ADM i have added the code below .

Comment: @Unsubtle Can you please also describe what exactly you're trying to do ?

Comment: I want that when i press back button on the fragment i must be redirected to it's parent activity UserProfileActivity and  not to that fragment.

Comment: Add your Fragment to backstage it will automatically will be redirected to last viewed Fragment

Comment: Woods 3, even after calling addToBackStack() still it's not working

Answer (score 0):

Just activities handle back-pressed event.
So you should handle back-pressed event in your fragment.
Take look at following link:
[How to implement onBackPressed() in Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments)