# How I can retrieve current fragment in NavHostFragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

I tried to find a method in the new Navigation components but I didn't find anything about that.

I have the current destination with :

```
mainHostFragment.findNavController().currentDestination
```

But I can't get any reference to the displayed fragment.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to handle it mannually

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @ianhanniballake My host Activity need references to communicate with its fragments

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Reference to the displayed fragment (AndroidX):

java

```
public Fragment getForegroundFragment(){
    Fragment navHostFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    return navHostFragment == null ? null : navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
}
```

kotlin

```
val navHostFragment: Fragment? =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.get(0)
```

Here `nav_host_fragment` is an ID
of the `fragment` tag in your `activity_main.xml` with `android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"`

Comment: in my case ?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.last() gives me current fragment

Comment: Wow, hacky answers. childFragmentManager.findFragmentById exists.

Comment: How is `childFragmentManager.findFragmentById` gonna help if they want to check what is the current fragment?

Answer (score 50):

Navigation does not provide any mechanism for getting the implementation (i.e., the Fragment itself) of the current destination.

As per the [Creating event callbacks to the activity](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments#EventCallbacks), you should either communicate with your Fragment by

- Having the Fragment register a callback in its `onAttach` method, casting your Activity to an instance of an interface you provide
- [Use a shared `ViewModel`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing) that your Activity and Fragment use to communicate.

Comment: All links show how to communicate between fragments. But how we can call fragment method from activity if navigation does not provide any mechanism for getting the implementation of the current destination?

Comment: @Sever - see [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119800853) and how to use `getPrimaryNavigationFragment()` to retrieve the current Fragment.

Comment: Big thanks. It works.

val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment as NavHostFragment

val yourFragment = currentFragmentClassName.childFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment as YourFragment

Comment: @ianhanniballake: Sorry, I didn't understand is there a way to get the foreground fragment by means of `getPrimaryNavigationFragment()` now or they are  going to provide such opportunity in the future only!?

Comment: Well, to share ViewModel between two fragments, one of them must be its owner. And the other one must find that owner in order to fetch that ViewModel. So… just never use Navigation, it's retarded.

Comment: It is incomprehensible why Navigation does not maintain a list of fragments, for example needed when MainActivity wants to call a method in a child fragment. In consequence, you need to use the "good old ways" for that, and then, whats the point of introducing a Navigation system? I don@t get it.

Answer (score 30):

You can do something like this:

```
  override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

        val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.first() as? NavHostFragment
        if(navHostFragment != null) {
            val childFragments = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments
            childFragments.forEach { fragment ->
                fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
            }
        }
    }
```

But for more advanced communication **Listeners with callback methods** registered in **Fragment.onAttach()** (`Fragment -> Activity rather one direction communication`) and **SharedViewModel** (`bidirectional`, important to have `ViewModelProviders, and Lifecycle owner that is scoped to getActivity()` rather)

Comment: You can remove `as? NavHostFragment` and make the if-statement `if (navHostFragment is NavHostFragment)`

Answer (score 14):

Based on other answers

```
Fragment navHostFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
Fragment fragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);

((Your Fragment Class) fragment).(public method inside the fragment)
```

worked for me

Answer (score 9):

Using Michal's answer I wrote this extension function for testing:

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
fun <F : Fragment> AppCompatActivity.getFragment(fragmentClass: Class<F>): F? {
    val navHostFragment = this.supportFragmentManager.fragments.first() as NavHostFragment

    navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments.forEach {
        if (fragmentClass.isAssignableFrom(it.javaClass)) {
            return it as F
        }
    }

    return null
}
```

Used like this:

```
val myFragment = activity.getFragment(MyFragment::class.java)
```

Comment: You can squish this down to `inline fun <reified T : Fragment> FragmentManager.findFragmentByClass(): T? =
        fragments.firstOrNull { it is T } as T?`

Answer (score 5):

You can do like this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
   
    NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragment);
    int id=navController.getCurrentDestination().getId();
    if(id == R.id.startGameFragment ){
        selectedPosition(0);
    } else if(id == R.id.gameFragment ){
        selectedPosition(1);
    } else if(id == R.id.endGameFragment){
        selectedPosition(2);
    }
}

private void selectedPosition(int pos){
    for (int i = 0; i >=nav_view.getMenu().size(); i++) {
        nav_view.getMenu().getItem(pos).setChecked(false);

    }
    nav_view.getMenu().getItem(pos).setChecked(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I post my complete answer with androidx. **Care : in my case i needed to retrieve one of the child fragment** (could not be the first).

In *MainActivity* you should have something like :

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                 R.id.mytest, R.id.nav_help)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
...
```

Then you have to create a method to retrieve the good fragment.

```
 private MyTestFragment getMyTestFragment(){
        MyTestFragment resultFragment = null;
        Fragment navHostFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        if(navHostFragment != null && navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager() != null) {
            List<Fragment> fragmentList = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
            for (Fragment fragment : fragmentList) {
                if (fragment instanceof MyTest) {
                    resultFragment = (MyTest) fragment;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return resultFragment;
    }
```

Finally you get it.

Answer (score 2):

From an Activity which has NavHostFragment, below code snippet can be used to retrieve the instance of the Active Fragment.

kotlin.

```
val currentFragment = mNavHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.primaryNavigationFragment()
```

java

```
Fragment navHostFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
Fragment currentFragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
```

Comment: Small correction for kotlin: it should be `primaryNavigationFragment` at the end, i.e. without a function call

Answer (score 0):

Really the best and correct way to handle this is to use an interface. View models should really be used for passing data between the activity and fragments. Here is how I solved this problem:

Create interface

```
interface NavigationInterface {
    fun referenceCourseListFragment(fragment: CourseListFragment)
    fun referenceCouseDetailFragment(fragment: CourseDetailInfoFragment)
}
```

Make sure activity implements interface

```
class NotesActivity : AppCompatActivity(), NavigationInterface {}
```

Make sure to create lateinit var for each fragment you need to reference and then

```
private lateinit var courseListFragment: CourseListFragment
private lateinit var courseDetailInfoFragment: CourseDetailInfoFragment
```

Now in each fragment in the onCreateView method, make sure to create the interface listener and passback the fragment with the interface

```
private lateinit var navigationInterface: NavigationInterface

override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    //establish interface communication
    activity?.let {
        instantiateNavigationInterface(it)
    }
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_course_list, container, 
    false)
    navigationInterface.referenceCourseListFragment(this)
    return fragmentView
}
```

Now back in the activity, you should be able to instantiate your fragment objects for reference via interface callback

```
override fun referenceCourseListFragment(fragment: CourseListFragment) {
    courseListFragment = fragment
}

override fun referenceCouseDetailFragment(fragment: CourseDetailInfoFragment) 
{
    courseDetailInfoFragment = fragment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is chance of exceptions, so you can use interface callback this is solid way to communicate from one end to other end only pass reference check below code.

> Fragment A(){ interface ClickPostItemListener {
> fun onClicked(position: Int)
> }
>
> ```
> val itemListener = object : ClickPostItemListener{
>     override fun onClicked(position: Int) {
>         postBackNForth(position)
>     }
>
> }  } Fragment B(clickItem:ClickPostItemListener ){ clickItem() }
> ```