# Android Navigation Architecture Component - Get current visible fragment

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack

Before trying the Navigation component I used to manually do fragment transactions and used the fragment tag in order to fetch the current fragment.

`val fragment:MyFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag):MyFragment`

Now in my main activity layout I have something like:

```
<fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host"
        app:navGraph= "@navigation/nav_item"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost= "true"
        />
```

How can I retrieve the current displayed fragment by the Navigation component? 
Doing

`supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host)`

returns a `NavHostFragment` and I want to retrieve my shown 'MyFragment`.

Thank you.

Comment: There is no way to retrieve the current fragment
https://stackoverflow.com/a/50689587/1268507

What are you trying to achieve? maybe there is some other solution for it.

Comment: I needed from my fragment to start a camera intent, take a picture and use the image taken. To do so, I've started an activity and waited for result in the `onActivityResult` of my main activity. Since I could not get the fragment, I simply moved all this into the fragment itself and seems to work.

Comment: Do you want to perform an operation on that fragment object. Or just you want which fragment is shown ?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

I managed to discover a way for now and it is as follows:

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host);
navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
```

In case of course you know it is the first fragment. I am still investigating a way without this. I agree it is not the best way but that should be something for now.

Comment: It's great to see a working solution. I gave up on this and started using a shared viewModel between the activity and fragment, This means that I can pass events between them without the need of callbacks or direct access.

Comment: As mentioned in this bug report issue https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119800853 this is not the correct method to do it. Please consider changing the correct answer !

Comment: As it is mentioned, it is not the solution, it is a workaround until a proper solution is found.

Comment: In my case, the top fragment is not the one by zero index, but the one at the last index

Comment: In general you don't need to do that. If you need to do that there is a flaw in your architecture. At least if you combine it with navigation graph.

Comment: Andrei: in my case, I have a ProgressBar (waiting spinner) in main activity, and I now want to add a cancel button on the spinner. The cancel button in main activity needs to send a message to the fragment to cancel the operation. Should I ditch this approach, and instead create a ProgressBar view inside each fragment? It seems to me that "flawed architecture" can be another word for "this is hard to do with this (flawed?) platform"

Comment: Add it as a separate question and link it here.

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 3

Comment: In the docs, it says "The order of the fragments in the list is the order in which they were added or attached." So I did this and it should be a little safer. But still not the best way.. `navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments.firstOrNull { it.isVisible }`

Comment: This works, many thanks. I tried getPrimaryNavigationFragment() as suggested in the bug tracker but it doesn't get the job done.

Comment: getPrimaryNavigationFragment() fails to find the navHostFragment when you programmatically set a graph and you are on the startDestination. findViewById doesn't fail in that situation.

Comment: Based on this solution I've created a kotlin function that can check whether the current fragment is of a specific type (instead of the id): `navHostFragment!!.childFragmentManager.fragments.any {  it.javaClass == fragmentClass && it.isVisible }` Works quite similar. Hope it'll help anyone!

Comment: it looks ugly, hardcoded `get(0)`

Answer (score 91):

There is no way I can find to retrieve the current fragment instance. However, you can get the ID of lastly added fragment using the code below.

```
navController.currentDestination?.getId()
```

It returns the ID in navigation file. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I needed to retrieve the fragment so I can interact with it. Since navController can't return it, I ended using a shared viewmodel to talk between activity and its fragments

Comment: i expected that the returned id matches the id in the nav xml, but it does not, so in other words you cannot check navController.getCurrentDestination().getId()==R.id.myfrag

Comment: @LeresAldtai It matches the ID of fragment in the navigation file.

Comment: Thank you @slhddn. Your comment helped me and was able to retrieve the id from the fragment and make this work. Added an answer here with my code in case useful to someone else. Cheers.

Comment: I still didn't understand how we can match if we are on the required fragment. 
findNavController().currentDestination.id value is 2131296642,
R.id.myFragment value is 1000319. 
Though the ids don't matter, posting it for understanding.
Basically I want to check and match which fragment I am on from a BaseFragment for setting up a common backpresscallback for all fragments.

Comment: @akhilsreekar When you're debugging, the R.id.xxx values are not the same for some reason. I see similar values as you described. However, even though both values appear different to the debugger, the comparison shows that they're equal...

Comment: @lulianT this will work: navController.currentDestination?.id == navController.graph[R.id.nav_graph_fragment_id].id

Answer (score 59):

You should look the childFragmentManager primaryNavigationFragment property of your nav fragment, this is where the current displayed fragment is referenced.

```
val navHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.main_nav_fragment)
    navHost?.let { navFragment ->
        navFragment.childFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment?.let {fragment->
                //DO YOUR STUFF
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This method is now documented in fragmentManager  https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119800853

Comment: this seems to be a bit of an issue. handling Up navigation i have to set up the actionbar to get call to onSupportNaigateUp()

Answer (score 36):

This seems like the cleanest solution. **Update:** Changed extension function to property. Thanks [Igor Wojda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211920/igor-wojda).

**1. Create the following extension**

```
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager

val FragmentManager.currentNavigationFragment: Fragment?
    get() = primaryNavigationFragment?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.first()
```

**2. In `Activity` with `NavHostFragment` use it like this:**

```
val currentFragment = supportFragmentManager.currentNavigationFragment
```

Comment: Nice - one this I would change - I would define extension as property `FragmentManager.currentNavigationFragment` (not as a function)

Comment: Returns `null` each time with Navigation lib version `2.3.5` and gradle version `7.0.2`. I am using a `NavDrawer` perhaps that is interfering? Either way, went with a different, but similar solution.

Answer (score 29):

Use `addOnDestinationChangedListener` in activity having `NavHostFragment`

**For Java**

```
 NavController navController= Navigation.findNavController(MainActivity.this,R.id.your_nav_host);

        navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onDestinationChanged: "+destination.getLabel());
            }
        });
```

**For Kotlin**

```
var navController :NavController=Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestinationChanged: "+destination.label);

    }
```

Comment: This returns `NavDestination` not a `Fragment`

Answer (score 22):

this might be late but for anyone who's still looking

```
val currentFragment = NavHostFragment.findNavController(nav_host_fragment).currentDestination?.id
```

then you can do something like

```
if(currentFragment == R.id.myFragment){
     //do something
}
```

note that this is for kotlin, java code should be almost the same

Comment: Here is the java code, https://stackoverflow.com/a/60539704/4291272

Comment: Fragment's getId() docs - 'Return the identifier this fragment is known by. This is either the android:id value supplied in a layout or the container view ID supplied when adding the fragment.' 
So the method of comparing ids may not work.

Answer (score 15):

My requirement is to get the current visible fragment from Parent activity,my solution is

```
 private Fragment getCurrentVisibleFragment() {
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
        if(fragment instanceof Fragment ){
            return fragment ;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

This may help some one with same  problem.

Comment: got Kotlin lang?

Comment: This works perfectly for me, not sure what's up with the other answers? Maybe this did not work previously but it works like a charm now.

Comment: worked for me after trying all above solutions

Answer (score 9):

```
navController().currentDestination?.id
```

will give you your current `Fragment`'s id where

```
private fun navController() = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment)
```

this id is the id which you have given in your `Navigation Graph XML` file under `fragment` tag. You could also compare `currentDestination.label` if you want.

Answer (score 8):

First, you get the current fragment by id, then you can find the fragment, depending on that id.

```
int id = navController.getCurrentDestination().getId();
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id);
```

Comment: how do you get navController?

Answer (score 5):

Found working solution.

```
private fun getCurrentFragment(): Fragment? {
    val currentNavHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_id)
    val currentFragmentClassName = ((this as NavHost).navController.currentDestination as FragmentNavigator.Destination).className
    return currentNavHost?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.filterNotNull()?.find {
        it.javaClass.name == currentFragmentClassName
    }
}
```

Comment: currentDestination as FragmentNavigator.Destination will crash if you are navigating to a dialog.

Comment: @TatiOverflow you are right .. this will cause a crash......
so you can solve it by checking for type........
check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75648904/5829679

Answer (score 4):

As per @slhddn answer and comment this is how I'm using it and retrieving the fragment **id from the nav_graph.xml** file:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar))

    val navController = findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment)

    ivSettingsCog.setOnClickListener {

        if (navController.currentDestination?.id == R.id.updatesFragment) // Id as per set up on nav_graph.xml file
        {
            navController.navigate(R.id.action_updatesFragment_to_settingsFragment)
        }

    }

}

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using navigation components, I got the current displayed fragment using this line of code:

```
val fragment = parentFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment
```

Answer (score 3):

From an Activity that uses `NavHostFragment`, you can use the code below to retrieve the instance of the `Active Fragment`.

```
val fragmentInstance = myNavHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.primaryNavigationFragment
```

Answer (score 3):

Within your activity, hosting the NavHostFragment we can write the following piece of code to fetch the instance of the currently displayed fragment

```
Fragment fragment = myNavHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragmentId)
if(fragment instanceOf MyFragment) {
  //Write your code here
}
```

Here ***R.id.navHostFragmentId*** is the resId for the NavHostFragment within your activity xml

Answer (score 2):

Make :

• in some button in your fragment:

```
val navController = findNavController(this)
  navController.popBackStack()
```

• In your Activity onBackPressed()

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
        val navController = findNavController(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val id = navController.currentDestination?.getId()
        if (id == R.id.detailMovieFragment){
            navController.popBackStack()
            return
        }

        super.onBackPressed()
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The first fragment in navhost fragment is the current fragment

```
Fragment navHostFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
if (navHostFragment != null) 
{Fragment fragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit more? Maybe by explaining your code.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide an explanation why and how your answer solves the problem.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Just test it. First we obtain the navigation's primary fragment which is used to allocate the fragments we inflate on navigation. Secondly we obtain the child fragment manager, which is the private fm the primary fragment has built inside to manage the different fragments we inflate. Lastly, all we have to do is obtain the last fragment inflated. Check a kotlin example working: val pF = supportFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment
val cF = pF!!.childFragmentManager.fragments.last() cF.updateMethod()

Answer (score 2):

Finally the working solution for those of you who are still searching
Actually it is very simple and you can achieve this using callback.

follow these steps:

1. Create a listener inside the fragment you want to get the instance from activity onCreate()

   ```
   public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

   private OnCreateFragment createLIstener;

   public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       createLIstener.onFragmentCreated(this);
       View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
       //findViews(root);
       return root;
   }

   @Override
   public void onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu, @NonNull MenuInflater inflater) {
       super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
       if (item.getItemId()==R.id.action_show_filter){
           //do something
       }
       return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
   }

   @Override
   public void onAttach(Context context) {
       super.onAttach(context);
       try {
           createLIstener = (OnCreateFragment) context;
       } catch (ClassCastException e) {
           throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() + " must implement OnArticleSelectedListener");
           }
       }

       public interface OnCreateFragment{
           void onFragmentCreated(Fragment f);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Implement your listener in the host Fragment/Activity

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeFragment.OnCreateFragment {

       @Override
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
           BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
          // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
          // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
           AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                   R.id.navigation_home,
                   R. ----)
           .build();
           NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
           NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);
           NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navView, navController);
       }

       @Override
       public void onFragmentCreated(Fragment f) {
           if (f!=null){
               H.debug("fragment created listener: "+f.getId());
               f.setHasOptionsMenu(true);
           }else {
               H.debug("fragment created listener: NULL");
           }
       }
   }
   ```

And that is everything you need to do the job.
Hop this help someone

Answer (score 2):

The best way I could figure out with 1 fragment, Kotlin, Navigation usage:

On your layout file add the tag: "android:tag="main_fragment_tag""

```
<fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host"
        app:navGraph= "@navigation/nav_item"
        android:tag="main_fragment_tag"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost= "true"
        />
```

On your Activity:

```
val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("main_fragment_tag") as NavHostFragment
val mainFragment = navHostFragment.childFragmentManager.fragments[0] as MainFragment
mainFragment.mainFragmentMethod()
```

Comment: Nice one! Best answer on the page +100000 ;)

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution for java

```
    NavHostFragment  navHostFragment= (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
    MyFragment  fragment = (MyFragment) navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
    fragment.doSomething();
```

Answer (score 2):

create extension function on Fragment Manager

```
inline fun <reified T : Fragment> FragmentManager.findNavFragment(hostId: Int): T? {

    val navHostFragment = findFragmentById(hostId)

    return navHostFragment?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.findLast {
        it is T
    } as T?
}
```

Now simply use it by giving id of the hosting fragment and get the specified fragment

```
    val myFragment: MyFragment? = supportFragmentManager.findNavFragment<MyFragment>(R.id.nav_host_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

can you please check with `getChildFragmentManager()` call with

```
NavHostFragment fragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host);
MyFragment frag = (MyFragment) fragment.getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(tag);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need the instance of your fragment, you can go with:

(Activity) => `supportFragmentManager.fragments.first().childFragmentManager.fragments.first()`

It's **very** ugly but from there you can check if it's an instance of the fragment you want to play around with

Answer (score 1):

On Androidx, I have tried many methods for finding out required fragment from `NavHostFragment`. Finally I could crack it with below method

```
public Fragment getFunctionalFragment (String tag_name)
{
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
    FragmentManager navHostManager = Objects.requireNonNull(navHostFragment).getChildFragmentManager();

    Fragment fragment=null;
    List fragment_list = navHostManager.getFragments();

    for (int i=0; i < fragment_list.size() ; i ++ )
    {
        if ( fragment_list.get(i) instanceof HomeFragment && tag_name.equals("frg_home")) {
            fragment = (HomeFragment) fragment_list.get(i);
            break;
        }
    }

    return fragment;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, before you post your answer, check it... Code is not clear. Another issue: if your are just bringing code, explain your solution a little bit, maximum when there are 16 more answers, so you should explain the Pros of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code works from me

```
NavDestination current = NavHostFragment.findNavController(getSupportFragmentManager().getPrimaryNavigationFragment().getFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0)).getCurrentDestination();

switch (current.getId()) {
    case R.id.navigation_saved:
        // WRITE CODE
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this might be late but may help someone later.

if you are using nested navigations you can get id like this in Kotlin

```
val nav = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.fragment_nav_host).currentDestination
```

and this is one of fragments in fragment_nav_host.xml

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/sampleFragment"
    android:name="com.app.sample.SampleFragment"
    android:label="SampleFragment"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_sample" />
```

and you can check all you need like this

```
if (nav.id == R.id.sampleFragment || nav.label == "SampleFragment"){}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val fragment: YourFragment? = yourNavHost.findFragment()
```

Note: `findFragment` extension function is located in `androidx.fragment.app` package, and it's generic function

Answer (score 1):

You should try get `fragmentHost` and then get its `first child` then `instanceof CustomFragment` .

Here example

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // get parent host
    Fragment fragmentHost = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.frame_container);
    // get first child fragment
    Fragment fragment = fragmentHost.getChildFragmentManager()
                                    .getFragments().get(0);
    if (fragment instanceof AccountFragment) {
        Log.d(STRING.TAG, "onBackPressed: home");
        if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();
            return;
        }
        
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        FancyToast.makeText(this, STRING.message_exit,
                            FancyToast.LENGTH_SHORT, FancyToast.INFO, false)
                  .show();
        
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, STRING.delayMillis);
    } else {
        Log.d(STRING.TAG, "onBackPressed: not home");
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined [Andrei Toaders answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732378/1849612) and [Mukul Bhardwajs answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56218631/1849612) with an `OnBackStackChangedListener`.

As an attribute:

```
private FooFragment fragment;
```

In my `onCreate`

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host);
FragmentManager navHostManager = Objects.requireNonNull(navHostFragment).getChildFragmentManager();
FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener listener = () -> {
        List<Fragment> frags = navHostManager.getFragments();
        if(!frags.isEmpty()) {
            fragment = (FooFragment) frags.get(0);
        }
};
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener((controller, destination, arguments) -> {
        if(destination.getId()==R.id.FooFragment){
            navHostManager.addOnBackStackChangedListener(listener);
        } else {
            navHostManager.removeOnBackStackChangedListener(listener);
           fragment = null;
        }
});
```

This way i can get a fragment, which will be displayed later on.
One even may be able to loop though `frags` and check multiple fragments with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 0):

I need to do this to setup a bottom navigation view and I did it this way:

```
val navController = Navigation.findNavController(requireActivity(), R.id.nav_tabs_home)
        val bottomNavBar: BottomNavigationView = nav_content_view
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavBar, navController)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to register a **fragment lifecycle callback**.

As per the original question, if your `NavHostFragment` is defined as...

```
<fragment
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/nav_host"
        app:navGraph= "@navigation/nav_item"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        app:defaultNavHost= "true"
        />
```

Then in your main activity `onCreate(..)`...

```
nav_host.childFragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(
    object:FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
        override fun onFragmentViewCreated(
            fm: FragmentManager, f: Fragment, v: View,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
        ) {
            // callback method always called whenever a
            // fragment is added, or, a back-press returns
            // to the start-destination
        }
    }
)
```

Other callback methods may be overridden to fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work in most situations
Try this:

```
val mainFragment = fragmentManager?.primaryNavigationFragment?.parentFragment?.parentFragment as MainFragment
```

or this:

```
val mainFragment = fragmentManager?.primaryNavigationFragment?.parentFragment as MainFragment
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
(navController.currentDestination as FragmentNavigator.Destination).className
```

It will return `canonicalName` of your fragment

Comment: This looks like Reflection

Answer (score 0):

Add the following method in your `Activity` class:

```
private Fragment getCurrentFragment() {
    NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host);
    if (navHostFragment != null) return navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager()
            .getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
    return null;
}
```

That's the shortest and cleanest solution for your problem.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version code for get currently active fragment in Navigation Graph

```
fun getCurrentFragmentInstance(activity: HomeActivity): Fragment? {
    val navHostFragment =
        activity.supportFragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment as NavHostFragment?
    val fragmentManager: FragmentManager = navHostFragment!!.childFragmentManager
    return fragmentManager.primaryNavigationFragment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit different in my app than all these answers

1. I created global variable in class myClass (myClass.kt)

   var currentFragmentName: String = "defaultValue"
2. When in Fragment I update it (TagsFragment.kt)

   currentFragmentName = "tagsFragment"
3. And in my case in back button (in parent activity of TagsFragment.kt)

   Log.d(TAG, myClass.currentFragmentName)
   val homeFragment = HomeFragment()
   if(InTorry.currentFragmentName=="tagsFragment"){
   setCurrentFragment(homeFragment,"fragment_tag_home")
   }

Answer (score 0):

```
private fun checkIfFragmentVisible(): Boolean {
    findNavController().currentDestination?.let { navDestination ->
        if (navDestination is FragmentNavigator.Destination)
            return navDestination.className == myFragment().javaClass.name

        if (navDestination is DialogFragmentNavigator.Destination)
            return navDestination.className == myFragment().javaClass.name
    }

    return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To communicate between Activity and fragment it is better and easier now to use a shared viewmodel.

just pass activity context while creating the viemmodel instance both in activity and fragment. Look at the code below

In Activity

```
SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    // ...
}
```

In Fragment

```
SharedViewModel sharedViewModel;

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // ...
    sharedViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(SharedViewModel.class);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -2):

In your activity define a fragment object. And from each fragment call this method by passing fragment object, like
So the static fragment object will be overridden by current showing fragment every time.

```
//method in MainActivity
private static Fragment fragment;

public void setFragment(Fragment fragment){
this.fragment = fragment;
}

//And from your fragment class, you can call
((<yourActivity in which fragment present>)getActivity()).setFragment(<your fragment object>);

//if you want to set it directly;
 ((<yourActivity in which fragment present>)getActivity()).fragment=<your fragment object>;
```

You can also set callback from fragment to activity, for a better approach and pass your current fragment object.

Comment: Thank you for your time. I was looking for something to use from the Navigation component itself.