# How can I show a fragment using a BottomNavigationView with valid back stack?

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, android-bottomnav

**Edit:**

The original question was `Is there a way to get a reference to a fragment that is displayed using a BottomNavigationView?`. But I've figured some things out and realized I was asking the wrong question.

I'd like to get a reference to a fragment that is being displayed using a `BottomNavigationView`.

This is how my `BottomNavigationView` is being setup. It's in `onCreate` of an Activity.

```
val navView: BottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)
val navController = findNavController(R.id.bottom_nav_view_nav_host)
    
val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(
    R.id.navigation_first_list,
    R.id.navigation_second
))

setupActionBarWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
    bottomNav.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

I've tried to get the fragment with `bottomNav.findFragment<TheFragmentType>()` it throws an exception.

Comment: What exception?

Comment: IllegalStateException

Comment: @Selvin feel free to point out my idiocy. But I'd like to figure out how to get a reference to the fragment.

Comment: I just don't get it why you think that BottomNavigationView has some fragment? it is kind of menu

Comment: I don't care if it's from the BottomNavigationView or AppBarConfiguration or navController, I just want access to the fragments displayed and the equivalent of BottomNavigationView is how it's done in iOS. I guess it's not done like this in Android. Care to point out how it is done?

Comment: I've looked through these docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/bottomnavigation/BottomNavigationView and haven't found anything promising

Comment: do you mean you wana get reference to the fragment [currently shown as content?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385067/android-navigation-architecture-component-get-current-visible-fragment)

Comment: Not necessarily, but that might work. In iOS, I can hold a reference to the "Fragment" (UIViewController) that I want, in the "Activity" then do as I need. Maybe I'm thinking of this the wrong way in Android.

Comment: What I'd really like to do is display a fragment from a push notification, but have the back stack still work correctly. I have this `MainActivity` that is shown if logged in, and that's where the app normally starts, then one of the Fragments that is represented in the bottom nav will push on another fragment with some `id` contained in the FCM push notification.

Comment: @Selvin I guess this isn't a common thing with Android?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was asking the wrong question originally. I can just use the navController to call the correct navigation component in order to show the right fragment with a back stack.

```
val bundle = bundleOf("someId" to "theId")
navController.navigate(R.id.action_navigation_list_to_details, bundle)
```