# Kotlin - Navigation Components - Navigation action/destination cannot be found from the current destination

Tags: kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

**ISSUE**

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Navigation action/destination xxxx/action_scanFragment_to_addVehicleFragment cannot be found from the current destination xxxx/addVehicleFragment
```

The error occurs when I do

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_scanFragment_to_addVehicleFragment)
```

in scanFragment. Which means that current destination is addVehicleFragment, but it should be scanFragment.

***I am clueless on how to approach this.***  See my earlier question for some troubleshooting and what really goes on in scanFragment:
[Kotlin - fragment lifecycle navigation issues; why does child fragment become current destination?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65750176/kotlin-fragment-lifecycle-navigation-issues-why-does-child-fragment-become-cu?noredirect=1#comment116251707_65750176)

I suspect my navigation setup is wrong, but I can't find the solution anywhere.

I'm posting my entire navigation implementation/code below.

**My nav_graph design:**
[image]

**My nav_graph XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/mainFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/scanFragment"
        android:name="xxxx.ui.scan.ScanFragment"
        android:label="@string/tab_bar_first_item_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_scan" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_scanFragment_to_addVehicleFragment"
            app:destination="@id/addVehicleFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/from_left"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/to_left" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/addVehicleFragment"
        android:name="xxxx.ui.scan.AddVehicleFragment"
        android:label="@string/add_vehicle_fragment_title_string"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_add_vehicle">
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_addVehicleFragment_to_scanFragment"
            app:destination="@id/scanFragment" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/mainFragment"
        android:name="xxxx.ui.main.MainFragment"
        android:label="@string/tab_bar_second_item_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_main" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="xxxx.ui.profile.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="@string/tab_bar_third_item_title"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile">

        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionMyVehicles"
            app:destination="@id/myVehiclesFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/to_left" />

        <action
            android:id="@+id/actionMyRooms"
            app:destination="@+id/myRoomsFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/from_right"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/to_left" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myVehiclesFragment"
        android:name="xxxx.ui.profile.MyVehiclesFragment"
        android:label="fragment_my_vehicles"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my_vehicles" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_myVehiclesFragment_to_profileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/from_left"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/to_right" />
    </fragment>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/myRoomsFragment"
        android:name="xxxx.ui.profile.MyRoomsFragment"
        android:label="fragment_my_rooms"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_my_rooms" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_myRoomsFragment_to_profileFragment"
            app:destination="@id/profileFragment"
            app:enterAnim="@anim/from_left"
            app:exitAnim="@anim/to_right" />
    </fragment>

</navigation>
```

**My Main Activity XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_activity_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tabBar"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph">

    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/tabBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:elevation="2dp"
        app:itemBackground="@color/light_gray"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/tab_bar_icon_tint_color"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/tab_bar" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var viewBinding: ActivityMainBinding
    private lateinit var tabBar: BottomNavigationView
    private lateinit var navHostFragment: NavHostFragment

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        println("MainActivity || onCreate ||")

        // Initialize viewBinding object
        viewBinding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        // Hide the default navigation bar; we implement our own
        supportActionBar!!.hide()
        
        viewBinding.loadingPageLayout.visibility = View.GONE

        setContentView(viewBinding.root)

        setupBottomBarNavigation()
    }

    private fun setupBottomBarNavigation() {
        tabBar = viewBinding.tabBar
        navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.navHostFragment) as NavHostFragment
        val navigationController = navHostFragment.navController
        val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(setOf(R.id.scanFragment, R.id.mainFragment, R.id.profileFragment))
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navigationController, appBarConfiguration)
        tabBar.setupWithNavController(navigationController)

        val navHost = supportFragmentManager.currentNavigationFragment
        println("Current navigation fragment: $navHost")

        
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() =
        Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.navHostFragment).navigateUp()
```

Please help a desperate fellow out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in Navigation Components but instead - I think - in my ImageAnalyzer. Turns out I accidentally allowed multiple calls to findNavController.navigate(). Now that I fixed that, my navigation issue is gone.

Comment: How did you fix this?

Comment: See my answer above

Comment: How to prevent double call? You didn't write how did this in above answer. @DanAbnormal

Comment: No I didn't. The reason is I don't have any general advice on how to prevent that; the issue was related to my specific code and most likely wouldn't help others.

Answer (score 9):

If someone had the same issues due to multiple clicks on the screen. It can be resolved by checking the current destination first before navigating

**For example**

Fragments A, B, and C

navigating from A to B while clicking on a button in fragment A that navigates to C might lead to crashes in some cases

for that you should check the current destination first as follows:

```
if(findNavController().currentDestination?.id==R.id.AFragment)
   findNavController().navigate(
   AFragmentDirections.actionAFragmentToCFragment()
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out earlier, this is likely to happen when there are multiple calls to navigate.

In my own peculiar case, I had mistakenly placed the navigate call inside a loop.

Only to discover after several hours of looking for a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You done write code for navigation, To handle multiple click on button use below code. Click with debounce

```
    fun View.clickWithDebounce(debounceTime: Long = 500L, action: () -> Unit) {
    this.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
        private var lastClickTime: Long = 0
        override fun onClick(view: View) {
            if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < debounceTime) return
            else action()
            lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
        }
    })
}
```