# How do one set an ID for a fragment displayed by a NavController and creating a Fragment object?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-navigation-graph

I created a navigation bar and ,I didn't understand how to create an ID for each fragment in grph.

navigation graph:

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/nav_home">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_home"
        android:name="com.mordechay.yemotapp.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" >
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@id/nav_explorer"
        android:name="com.mordechay.yemotapp.filseExplorerFragment"
        android:label="fragment_filse_explorer"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_filse_explorer" />
</navigation>
```

in the activity:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/nvgv_fragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph"
    />
```

And I wrote in the activity:

```
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_explorer);
```

It comes out null, what do I need to write to get the fragment?

I tried to get the fragment by writing the ID of the fragment found in the navigation graph.
But I get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already set your id's => android:id="@+id/nav_home" and android:id="@+id/nav_explorer".

At first, you need to declare your navigation controller.

```
val navigationController = findNavController(R.id.nvgv_fragment)
```

then you can check destination fragment with listener

```
navigationController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
    if (destination.id == R.id.nav_explorer) {
        // whatever you want to do
    }
}
```

But, if you only need an instance of displayed fragment, you can find the answer here:
[Current fragment instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51732378/13000604)

Comment: It did work. But I still couldn't get a fragment object, how did you manage to get a feagment object?

I wrote it, but fragment is still null.


    if (navDestination.getId() == R.id.nav_explorer) {
            fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_explorer);
            }

Comment: I need this to implement this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425415/19169874

Comment: Ok. You can find fragment instance with something like this:

   
 fun findFragmentInstance() {
        val fragmentHost = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment)
        val fragmentInstance = fragmentHost?.childFragmentManager?.fragments?.last()
        if (fragmentInstance is YourFragment) {
            // Do whatever you want with fragment
        }
        }

Comment: How is it in Java?

Comment: void findFragmentInstance() {
        Fragment fragmentHost = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        List<Fragment> fragmentList = fragmentHost.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments();
        Fragment fr = fragmentList.get(fragmentList.size() - 1);
        if (fr instanceof YourFragment) {
            // Do whatever you want with fragment
        }
    }

// Be careful, fragmentHost, childFragmentManager and fragmentsList might be null. You need to check it to avoid NullPointerException. Hope this helps.