# How to check which fragment is running at the moment. To make a condition out of this

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-navigation, android-api-31

I navigate to other fragments using navigation. And I want to add a condition that if, for example, (profile fragment) is running, then visibility = GONE for the header. Experts help to solve the problem[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wruf8.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUJHW.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOFFO.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPwW8.png)

How to find out which fragment is currently running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hey you can have a look at the below link to find which fragment is currently visible at a certain time

```
NavHostFragment navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host);
navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().get(0);
```

for more info

[Android Navigation Architecture Component - Get current visible fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385067/android-navigation-architecture-component-get-current-visible-fragment)