# Android - Get current fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

This question has been ask a lot, but i have not seen a recent answer.

This in contained in my main activity :

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation_map" />
```

I have tried

[image: fragment manager deprecated]

-> The fragment manager is deprecated

[image: SupportFragmentManager]

-> The support fragment manager does not work

**I would like to know what is the fragment loaded in my `FragmentContainerView`**

Comment: The Jetpack edition of `FragmentManager` is not deprecated. You appear to be using the framework `FragmentManager`, which *is* deprecated. "I would like to know what is the fragment loaded in my FragmentContainerView" -- call `findFragmentById()` on `FragmentManager`.

Comment: Use `supportFragmentManager` instead

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51385067/android-navigation-architecture-component-get-current-visible-fragment) will help you get the current fragment using navigation components

Comment: This will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50689206/how-i-can-retrieve-current-fragment-in-navhostfragment?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: The supportFragmentManager doesn't get me the fragment, maybe because i use a FragmentContainerView ?

Comment: I found out using the `supportFragmentManager` as shown in the 3d answer of the @NitinPrakash linked question. Thanks everyone !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll use the `supportFragmentManager` as suggested

The `findFragmentById` was not working for it though, but this seen in another linked question goes well :

```
navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.fragments.first()
```

And then the usual

```
wantedFragment = navHostFragment.getChildFragmentManager().getFragments().first()
```