# How to do something on back press instead of pop from backStack just for one fragment and still should able to work normally for other fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

I have an app in which there is a `FramLayout` with id `frame_container`.

My onCreate looks like this :-

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        hideKeyboard();
        editText = findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        editText.setSelection(editText.getText().toString().length());
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        frameLayout = findViewById(R.id.frame_container);
        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_container,new advancefunction());
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        frameLayout.animate().translationXBy(1000f);


    }
```

When I press a button it just brings my fragment with animation by using function :-

```
@Override
    public void advanceButton(View view) {

        frameLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        frameLayout.animate().translationXBy(-1000f).setDuration(500);
    }
```

So when I press backButton it goes to previous state but instead I want it to get `invisible` and `translationXby(1000f)` any suggestions how to achieve it as i am a new to android and still learning so a help would be great.

Comment: now it's not duplicate @arbuz a help would be great

Answer (score 0):

Just use `onBackPressed` function, who catches the listener from the back key inside your **Activity**

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
       //put your code here
    }
```

or

Use this one if you`re inside a **Fragment**

```
@Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        PUT YOUR CODE HERE
    }
```

Comment: where should I place onBackPressed function ?

Comment: put inside your Activity

Comment: Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24881908/7540393) if you want to do it inside a fragment

Comment: I dont think this is the best approach, I`ll edit my answer

Comment: `onDetach` will do the job

Comment: thing is that my FrameLayout variable is in MainActivity.java and my fragment is advaancefunction.java now where to put and how to use framelayout variable ? @LMaker

Comment: I think you should override onbackpress function inside your main activity by sorting out your target fragment

Comment: its really confuse to be honest, Can you provide your github repo or something?

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
}
```