# Handle `BackPressed` when we only have a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I have an `Activity` and it has only one `Fragment`. I want to handle `backpressed` functionality. When user presses back, program should go back to `Activity`. I know this is very simple but I have tried some solutions that are mentioned on Stackoverflow, but none of them worked. For example I tried this:

```
public void onBackPressed() {
int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {

        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.skoumal.com/en/android-handle-back-press-in-fragment/

Comment: I don't get your point

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya I tried your solution but when I press back, program go out.

Comment: You say that have only one fragment, but you are checking if there is another fragment in backStack, is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand all you want to do is when users press Back key on `MainActivity`

- If there are more than 1 fragments in the back stack just pop out the fragment
- If there is only 1 fragment in the back stack, first back press will be ignored and you would like to run some additional code. Then if users press back key again, your `MainActivity` will be finished.

Change your code to

```
private boolean ignoredFirstBackPressed = false;

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
    if (count == 1) {
        // If there is only one fragment in back stack
        if (!ignoredFirstBackPressed) {
            // additional code
            ignoredFirstBackPressed = true;
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack(); // or super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be correct. Did you add `Fragment` to backstack using `addToBackStack` ? Have a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments?rq=1). It's similar to yours.

Comment: I add Fragment to `addToBackStack` and return to my Activity. But my app show blank activity!

Comment: Can you show how you are creating and adding the fragment? May be you're using `SupportFragmentManager` for adding the fragment and `FragmentManager` is returning count 0.