# Cancelling a CountDownTimer on Physical Back Button Press in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using a `CountDownTimer` in a Fragment and trying to stop it if the user hit the physical back button in the phone. I have tried overriding `onPause`, `onDestroy`, `onStop`, `onDestroyView` but nothing seems to be working. Kind of lost here. Can some one give me a pointer here?

```
public class Foo extends Fragment {

    CountDownTimer myTimer;

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        myTimer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        myTimer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        myTimer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        myTimer.cancel();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_greenleft_no)
    public void goBack() {

        myTimer.cancel();
        Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).onBackPressed();
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.btn_greenright_yes)
    public void showSuccess(View view) {

        markAll();
        myTimer.cancel();
        (new MusicPlayer()).playSound(getContext(), "cheers.mp3");

        final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(snackBarView, R.string.congratulations, Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT);

        snackbar.show();
        myTimer.cancel();


    }


    private void startTimer(final View view) {

        int Seconds = 5;

        myTimer = new CountDownTimer(Seconds * 1000 + 1000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                String rem = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    Log.d("APP_DEBUG", "Timer: " + rem);

            }

            public void onFinish() {
                goBack();
                }
        }.start();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is my 2 cents. Fragment doesn't have an [onBackPressed()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()) method which is present in the `Activity` class. It gets called when physical back button is pressed by the user. Here is what docs says:

> Called when the activity has detected the user's press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.

What you can do is override the `onBackPressed()` method in the parent activity of your `Foo` fragment, then using an interface communicate to the fragment that back button was pressed by the user. Inside the fragment you can have the desired code to cancel the timer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425415/1306419) in the question [How to implement onBackPressed() in Fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments) can help with sample code.

Answer (score 3):

Try to modify `onBackPressed` in Your fragment's parent activity.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    // I assume this is the way how You add fragment to fragment manager
    //getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, Foo.getInstance(), Foo.TAG).commit()

    // Find fragment by its string TAG and when You get it, call to stop countDownTimer
    Foo foo = (Foo) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(Foo.TAG);
    if (foo != null) {
        foo.stopCountDownTimer();
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Next step is to declare in Your Foo fragment two things:

```
public static final String TAG = "Foo";
```

and

```
public void stopCountDownTimer() {
    myTimer.cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For fragment you cant use  **onBackPressed** method, Instead please use this code

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (getView() == null) {
        return;
    }
    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    getView().requestFocus();
    getView().setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP && keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
                myTimer.cancel();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to call countDownTime.finish() as well. I have used it and it works for me.

```
@Override
public void onDetach()
{
    super.onDetach();

    if (countDownTimer != null)
    {
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer.onFinish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `onBackPressed()`

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
            super.onBackPressed();
            myTimer.cancel();
            myTimer =null;
    }
```

Comment: Last time I checked Fragments doesn't have an `onBackPressed` method to override.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding an OnKeyListener in your fragment like this: 
Here "view" is the parent layout of your fragment , the one that hosts the timer.

```
view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
view.requestFocus();
view.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            Log.i(tag, "keyCode: " + keyCode);
            if( keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
               myTimer.cancel();
                return true;
            } 
            return false;
        }
    });
```