# How can I stop video recording when user presses the back button on an Android custom camera

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

### *NOTE:* This resembles a duplicate but none of the others solved my problem

@Hitesh Tarbundiya's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55175530/4268050) in **Step 2** solved my problem

I am using the [natario1 CameraView library](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) for android to record video.

I am working with a `Fragment`.

I have written code to

1. Stop the video recording
2. Save the recorded video
3. Update the media gallery with the newly created video file

But what I can't figure out now is where to call those methods when the user presses the back button or home button on their phone *before* the fragment is destroyed.

I have tried calling the methods from the `onPause()` `onStop()` `onDestroyView()` and `onDestroy()` but have not succeeded.

Would appreciate some advice, thanks.

Comment: try onBackPressed()

Comment: @HiteshTarbundiya 
I don't have access to that method in a `Fragment` class

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments

Comment: @ADM I tried to implement the solution in the stackoverflow answer you linked to.

 
While I'am able to trigger code to run when the back button is pressed I think the issue now is that the `cameraView.close()` method is running in another thread so even when I call it in the implemented `onBackPressed()` in the `Fragment` it doesn't work. 
the `.close()` method returns `void` a good return value (say a Boolean) would have been great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this, may solved your issue.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
  if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
   //Wtire your code for stop video, on back press
    mMediaRecorder.stop();
    mMediaRecorder.reset();
   }else{
    super.onBackPressed();
   }         
}
```

If you are in fragment then follow this step.

Step 1:create one interface file

```
public interface IOnBackPressed {
/**
 * If you return true the back press will not be taken into account, otherwise the activity will act naturally
 * @return true if your processing has priority if not false
 */
boolean onBackPressed();
}
```

Step 2: in your Activity class implement this,

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
@Override public void onBackPressed() {
Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_container);
   if (!(fragment instanceof IOnBackPressed) || !((IOnBackPressed) fragment).onBackPressed()) {
      super.onBackPressed();
   }
 } 
}
```

Step 3: Now in your fragment class implemnt interface write like this,

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements IOnBackPressed{
@Override
public boolean onBackPressed() {
   if (myCondition) {
        if (mMediaRecorder != null) {
         //Wtire your code for stop video, on back press
         mMediaRecorder.stop();
         mMediaRecorder.reset();
        }
      return true; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: I don't have access to that method in a `Fragment` class

Comment: ok, i will give you some code for help to implement backpress in fragment, if you required ?