# Android: How to hide bottom sheet when back button is pressed in fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, fragment

I have a fragment with a bottom sheet inside and I want to hide it when back button is pressed, then with the second back go to previous fragment,I tried to use `onBackPressed` but it doesn't work. `setOnKeyListener()` it doesn't work too. Some help solution, wellcome.

Answer (score 0):

this may help you !

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    touchToBack++;

    if (touchToBack== 1) {
        if (bottomSheetBehavior!=null && bottomSheetBehavior.getState() !=
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
            bottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
            touchToBack= 0;
            return;
        }

    }

    if (touchToBack== 1 || touchToBack> 1) {
        if (bottomSheetBehavior!=null && bottomSheetBehavior.getState() ==
                BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN) {
                           touchToBack= 0;
                           super.onBackPressed();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I can not use onBackPressed() directly on fragment, and Main Activity can not see BottomSheetBehavior that is in my fragment

Comment: make it static! and make sure it is not empty!

Comment: I want a fragment where i can edit a profile image, when I click on a edit imageview it opens the bottomsheet with options of access to gallery and delete image. Everything works good, the problem is when I want to go back and hide the bottomsheet before and then to go back to the previous fragment.

Comment: see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5448653/how-to-implement-onbackpressed-in-fragments