# How can I program the back button of the mobile to go to the main activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm developing an app where I have a `menu` with `Buttons`, and in each `Button` the user go through `Fragments`. When I press the back `Button` of the phone (the first of three `buttons` of the device, the arrow) it goes to the previous `Fragment`, but I want to go back to the `menuscreen`.
How can I program that `Button` to open the `menu` `activity`?

Comment: Check I have updated my answer, hope it helps, consider accepting if it works for you, ask for clarification otherwise

Answer (score 2):

You may try overriding `onBackPressed()` and then routing all back presses to the menu activity:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent goToMenuActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourActivity.class);
    startActivity(goToMenuActivity);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I press the back button of the phone (the first of three buttons
>   of the device, the arrow) it goes to the previous fragment

That means you are using back-stack for your fragments.

**First Solution**

The simple solution is just removing (not using) back-stack

**Second Solution**

override OnBackStack then manipulate your activity

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

   finish();
   startActivity(new Intent(this, MenuActivity.class));

}
```

**Third solution**

it requires more effort to implement but you may try. [@MaximeJallu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46425415/8342718) solution

1 - Create Interface

```
    public interface IOnBackPressed {
    /**
     * If you return true the back press will not be taken into account, otherwise the activity will act naturally
     * @return true if your processing has priority if not false
     */
    boolean onBackPressed();
}
```

2 - Prepare your Activity

```
  public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override public void onBackPressed() {
    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_container);
       if (!(fragment instanceof IOnBackPressed) || !((IOnBackPressed) fragment).onBackPressed()) {
          super.onBackPressed();
       }
    } ...
}
```

Finally in your Fragment:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements IOnBackPressed{
   @Override
   public boolean onBackPressed() {
       if (myCondition) {
            //action not popBackStack
            return true; 
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **There is two methods**

link [this](http://How%20to%20handle%20back%20button%20in%20activity)
1

```
@override
public void onBackPressed(){
  super.onBackPressed();
  finish();
}
```

2

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
   {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) 
        {
            return false; 
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```